# vim settings does not work correctly in zsh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, vim, zsh

I just switched my shell from bash to zsh and I noticed that `zsh` is not using same  version of vim that I use in bash. Wondering why that might be the case? Do I need to set some config?

## EDIT

remove other stuffs

Comment: Two issues --> two questions, thanks.

Comment: I would take one out. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either have defined an *alias* for `vim` in one of them, or the value of the `PATH` variable is different.

Comment: good call.... I indeed have an alias!